Matrix becomes positive definite?
Define $d(A, B)=\max_{i, j}|a_{ij}-b_{ij}|$. Is it true that if $d(A, cI)$ is "sufficiently small", where $I$ is the identity matrix and $c>0$, then $A$ is positive definite? I am curious as to whether this is true and how I might prove it. For example, matrices like
$$\begin{bmatrix}1.001 & -0.0001 &0.001 \\
0.0002 & 1.0009 & 0.0007 \\
-0.0003 & -0.0006 & 1\end{bmatrix}$$

No. Your matrix isn't even symmetric. If you assume that the perturbation is symmetric, then yes.

How would you show it in the symmetric case?

@AadiMRane Take a look at the question linked in the other comment for the symmetric case
